# d3.js - how to insert new sibling elements

Tags: javascript, dom, d3.js

I have a problem with inserting new siblings to existing elements.

I have this structure

```
<svg> 
  <g> 
    <path class="data"></path> 
    <path class="data"></path> 
  </g>
</svg>
```

and want this structure

```
<svg> 
  <g> 
    <path class="data"></path> 
    <text></text>
    <path class="data"></path> 
    <text></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

but if I use the d3.js insert function

```
d3.select("g").insert("text", "path.data");
```

i get the following (despite selecting by class name)

```
<svg> 
  <g> 
    <text></text>
    <path class="data"></path> 
    <path class="data"></path> 
  </g>
</svg>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

First of all, it's worth noting that the second argument in the insert function is a **before** selector. Furthermore, chained operations act on the left hand result.

So you have done

```
// select all the g elements (only 1)
d3.select("g")
    // For each g, insert a text element before "path.data"
    .insert("text", "path.data");
```

You want to perform an operation for each child ".data", so you need to select each of the ".data" elements and perform an action for each of them. I'm not entirely sure how d3 expects you to insert an element after a specific child. I find it much easier to use the DOM API to do the element creation and insertion, but using the d3.each function to iterate over a selection.

```
d3.selectAll("g > .data").each(function () {
    var t = document.createElement('text');
    this.parentNode.insertBefore(t, this.nextSibling);       
});​
```

Comment: Thank you Matt. This does what I want. This is probably the best solution anyway since, the d3.js insert function does only support constants as selectors (at the moment). So you cannot use "this.nextSibling" as a selector. I an ideal world the corresponding d3.js function should look something like this: d3.select(this.parentNode).insert("text", this);

Comment: Adding new elements with `.each` and `document.createElement `adds the node to the document, but it is removed from being displayed for some reason. Supposedly, it's possible to use d3's `insert() t`o do this, but the "before" selector passed to `insert()` will only select a single element.