# Problems when using the insert() function in d3 java library when trying to insert SVG elements before another

Tags: javascript, insert, d3.js, selector

I have problems using the [insert() function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-insert) of the d3 visualization library. Better to say I do not understand how to use the "before selector". I red the examples [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/d3-js/JD7k8pz3D-M) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029571/d3-js-how-to-insert-new-sibling-elements), but this dod not help.

I create an svg element and append an  element to it. Then I append foreignObject-element to the group and would like afterward insert an rectangle before the foreignObject-element.

Here is my code

```
var body = d3.select("body");

var svg = body.append("svg")
    .attr("width", '100%')
    .attr("height", '100%');

var group = svg.append("svg:g");

var html = group.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("x", 50)
    .attr("y", 25)
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .append("xhtml:div")
    .style("font", "14px 'Helvetica Neue'")
    .html("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eu enim quam.");

var rect1 = group.insert("svg:rect", html)
    .attr("rx", 6)
    .attr("ry", 6)
    .attr("x", 5/2)
    .attr("y", 5/2)
    .attr("id", "rect")
    .attr("width", 250)
    .attr("height", 120)
    .style("fill", 'white')
    .style("stroke", d3.scale.category20c())
    .style('stroke-width', 5);
```

Here is a (non)working [Jsfidle example](http://jsfiddle.net/GCTuD/)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029571/d3-js-how-to-insert-new-sibling-elements) may help.

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly the same question I mention in my description. Already found and read that, but it did not help.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: Try passing an id to the before select, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/GCTuD/3/

```
var rect1 = group.insert("svg:rect", "#foreign_object")
```

You cannot select by element tag name, only by constants (such as an id), as specified in the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-insert):

> The name and before selector must be specified as constants, though in
>   the future we might allow inserting of existing elements or a function
>   to generate the name or selector dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. Your Jsfidle example seems to be false, the rectangle is drawn after the foreignObject element. My problem is, that I do not understand how can I convert the variable in a selector or constant.

Comment: See my edit and new jsfiddle above. I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Good answer! Btw, you can do that as well group.insert("svg:rect", "g")