# Creating a table with D3 where two rows are siblings

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm creating a table with D3 that is sourced from a `CSV` file. I have no problem making rows to match each row in the `CSV`, but I have one column that has lengthy text data. For readability, I want to have that column in a cell underneath the others that spans across the entire table:

```
<table>
 ...
    <tr>
        <td>col1</td><td>col2</td>...<td>colN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="N">lengthy text</td>
    </tr>
 ...
</table>
```

However, D3 doesn't seem to have a good way to add sibling elements. I've read elsewhere ([d3.js - how to insert new sibling elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029571/d3-js-how-to-insert-new-sibling-elements)) to iterate over the already created first sibling elements and add the second...however I have data from the source row that I need to add in the sibling.

If I try:

```
var row = mytable.enter().append("tr").attr("class","firstrow");
var row2 = mytable.enter().append("tr").attr("class","secondrow");
```

All the secondrows get appended after ALL the firstrows.

If I try:

```
var row = mytable.enter().append("tr").attr("class","firstrow");
var row2 = mytable.insert("tr").attr("class","secondrow");
```

The secondrows get appended inside the firstrows.

This has the same result as above:

```
var row = mytable.enter().append("tr").attr("class","firstrow");
var row2 = mytable.insert("tr","tr").attr("class","secondrow");
```

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
For those who want something to play with, here's the whole shebang:

```
function createTable(source, title, columns, hook) {
var tableOutput = d3.select(hook).append("table");
var headingRow = tableOutput.append("tr");
var datasets = [source];

var tableHeadings = headingRow.selectAll(".column_headings")
.data(columns)
.enter().append("th").text(function (d) {return d;}).attr("class","column_headings");

var tableChart = function(source) {
    d3.csv(source, function(d) {
        return {
            thing1: +d.thing1,
            thing2: d.thing2,
            lengthything: d.lengthything, //the text that needs to go in the second row
            link: d.link //wrap a link around lenthything
        };
    },
function(error, data) {
    //do the table
    var mytable = tableOutput.selectAll().data(data);

    var row = mytable.enter().append("tr").attr("class","firstrow");
    var row2 = mytable.insert("tr","tr").attr("class","secondrow");

    row.append("td").attr("class","numeric").text(function(d) { return d.thing1 });
    row.append("td").text(function(d) { return d.thing2 });

});
};

tableChart(datasets[0]);
```

}

Comment: I would reformat the data to conform to the structure you want to display.

Comment: I'm not in control of the data source.

Comment: You don't need to be, you can reformat in Javascript.

Comment: Where? Before the d3.csv(source, function(d) {}) call? The source is the filename.

Comment: any chance we can get a  jsfiddle   to play with ?  Here's a possible related link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338098/problems-when-using-the-insert-function-in-d3-java-library-when-trying-to-inse?lq=1

Comment: jsfiddle can't handle the csv file I don't think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I don't think there's a strictly D3 way of doing it though (still open to D3 only answers).

```
function(error, data) {
    //do the table
    var mytable = tableOutput.selectAll().data(data);

    var row = mytable.enter().append("tr").attr("class","firstrow");
    //var row2 = mytable.insert("tr","tr").attr("class","secondrow");
    //the above is replaced with:

    d3.selectAll("tr.firstrow").each(function(d) {
        p = this.parentNode; //grab the parent table element
        r = document.createElement("tr");
        r.setAttribute("class","secondrow");
        c = document.createElement("td");
        c.setAttribute("colspan","8");
        a = document.createElement("a");
        a.setAttribute("href",d.link);
        a.innerText = d.message;

        //glue everything together
        c.appendChild(a);
        r.appendChild(c);

        //insert the second row after the first
        p.insertBefore(r,this.nextSibling);
    });

    row.append("td").attr("class","numeric").text(function(d) { return d.thing1 });
    row.append("td").text(function(d) { return d.thing2 });

});
```

It's ugly but works. Does anyone have a cleaner/more efficient way to do it?

Comment: This is the other way you could go, but yeah it is a little uglier. My suggestion (and those of others) rely on changing your data array. Think of the data you get from the server as your "model", and you need to reshape that data to fit your view -- that could be called a "view model." I think you should go with what you understand, for now, but creating visualizations in d3 is 100% dependent on the structure of the data you pass in. You should feel comfortable manipulating that data to fit the visualization structure, even if the default server data (the model) does not.

Comment: Well my data is coming from a CSV file, not a response from a server (like if it came via JSON I'd have plenty of chance to preprocess it. D3 does the CSV file reading pretty faff-free, so that's a huge advantage that I don't want to lose or have to 'roll my own'.) I really think it's a D3 weakness that there isn't a way to deal with sibling elements.

Answer (score 1):

Restructure your data. Instead of having each object in your N-sized data array correspond to a row, modify your data such that you add N number of new rows in between the existing rows, where each new row is an object containing the lengthy text and and an identifier that you can use to distinguish it from the other rows.

Comment: Do you have code to illustrate this? I'm not really seeing how this can be done with D3.

Comment: It's more of a Javascript exercise than d3. Essentially, you have a CSV in the form of an array. Each item in that array corresponds to a single row in the CSV, correct? D3 loves arrays, and will render out each item in that array as a single <tr>. But you actually want two <trs> per original row in the CSV, where the second row contains just the value of that particularly long column. So, loop through your data array and add a new row after each original row. If you set up a JS fiddle that condenses your use case, I'd be happy to help you edit it to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: @dochran does my posted answer match with what you're saying?