# d3 error : "Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I try to addd subtitle to a title list thnaks to d". Unfortunately I am stucked with an 
error :

```
HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy
```

Here is the extremly simple code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>           
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
            <script>
            function start2()
            {
                data               =  [ { titre : " subtitle 1"  }   , 
                                        { titre : " subtitle 2"  }   , 
                                        { titre : " subtitle 3"  }   , 
                                        { titre : " subtitle 4"  }   , 
                                        { titre : " subtitle 5"  }   ]   ;

                Updated_dom= d3 .selectAll  (   "h1"    )
                                .data       (   data    );

                Updated_dom.append     (   "h2"    )
                           .text       (   function(d){ return d.titre;}   );

                Updated_dom .enter()
                            .append("h1")
                            .text(  function(d) {  return "new title : " + d.titre ;  }   );

            }

            </script>
        </head>
        <body onload=start2()>
                <h1>Title 1</h1>
                <h1>Title 2</h1>
                <h1>Title 3</h1>

        </body>
    </html>
```

which give me a partial result before dying on the error :

```
<body onload="start2()">
    <h1>
        Title 1
        <h2>
             subtitle 1
        </h2>
    </h1>
    <h1>
        Title 2
         <h2>
             subtitle 2
        </h2>
    </h1>
    <h1>
        Title 3
        <h2>
            subtitle 3
         </h2>
    </h1>
</body>
```

Any idea of what is happening ?

Furthermore I was wondering how to have the "h2" going "after" the "h1" (rather than "under" as of today), ie getting :

```
    <h1>
         title 1
    </h1>
    <h2>
        subtitle 1
    </h2>
```

Help on this second point welcome too ;)

Thanks,
romain.

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/0w85dyro/

Comment: doesn't in firefox for me :(

Comment: And still : would you have any clue about the 2nd question ? how to append an"h2" AFTER the "h1" rather than BELOW ?

Comment: No problems here in Chrome. D3 isn't suited well to generating the structure you're looking for in this context, I would put everything into data and then generate all the elements. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029571/d3-js-how-to-insert-new-sibling-elements) may help.

Comment: In chrome I got the following error : Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type 'h1' may not be inserted inside nodes of type '#document'.

Comment: As I've said, the code you've posted works fine for me.

Comment: :-( I am on chrome 38.0.2125.122 which one do you use ?